# How to create private S3 bucket with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create a private S3 bucket. If I create a private bucket with AWS console, it works. If I create a private bucket with Terrafom, the bucket is created, but it is always public.

**Code**

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "audio" {
  bucket = "my-dev-audio"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "audio" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.audio.id
  acl = "private"
}
```

**Logs**

```
[...]
# aws_s3_bucket_acl.audio will be created
+ resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "audio" {
    + acl    = "private"
    + bucket = (known after apply)
    + id     = (known after apply)

    + access_control_policy {
        + grant {
            + permission = (known after apply)

            + grantee {
                + display_name  = (known after apply)
                + email_address = (known after apply)
                + id            = (known after apply)
                + type          = (known after apply)
                + uri           = (known after apply)
              }
          }

        + owner {
            + display_name = (known after apply)
            + id           = (known after apply)
          }
      }
  }
```

**Screenshots**

In the list of buckets my bucket is shown as public.

[image]

In the permission tab of my bucket, the bucket is shown as public.

[image]

**Environment**

- Terrerform 1.2.1
- AWS Provider 4.45.0

**Research**

- I read [Resource: aws_s3_bucket_acl](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_acl), but I can't see any difference between the exmaple and my code.

**Question**

How can I create a private S3 bucket with Terraform?

Comment: You actually want this: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_public_access_block.

Comment: @MarkoE Ok, it worked. Could you write an answer? I would accept the answer. However, it would be nice if you elaborate the difference and typical recommend a solution. For testing I blocked/ignore all.

Comment: Great to hear that. I'll try to write something meaningful. :)

Comment: Private is always the default for S3 buckets (and objects). You should not have to indicate this at all. Also, block public access is a related, but different, thing. It's a centralized policy that prevents objects from being made public. BPA is a valuable secondary security mechanism, assuming that you don't ever want to allow objects to be public in that bucket.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what "block public access" (Öffentlichen Zugriff beschränken) means. It's possible for a bucket to be private (`acl = "private"`) and for block public access not to be enabled. Turning this setting on prevents any objects being made public, but if it's off that does not necessarily mean anything in the bucket is currently public. As noted above you can enabled "block public access" independently to prevent anything being unintentionally made public (recommended).

Comment: @NathanGriffiths + @jarmod: Thank your for the explanation. However, it was my intention to disable public access at all. If I understand you right, I do not need `aws_s3_bucket_acl` in my case.

Comment: If you want to block all public access to the bucket then use [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_public_access_block). Note that BPA can also be set at AWS account level (so applies to all S3 buckets).

Answer (score 1):

S3 buckets are private by default, s3 bucket acl is different from bucket privacy.
[S3 bucket ACL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/iam-policies-and-bucket-policies-and-acls-oh-my-controlling-access-to-s3-resources/#:%7E:text=An%20S3%20ACL%20is%20a,full%20control%20over%20the%20resource.)